# Automatically switch between two column and one column layout with CSS

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a simple two column layout with fixed widths.

```
<div id='box'>
    <div id='ontop'>Ontop</div>
    <div id='column1'>Column1</div>
    <div id='column2'>Column1</div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#box { width: 20em; }
#column1 {width: 12em;}
#column2 {float: left; width: 8em;}
```

I would like to have `column1` expand to "100%" if `column2` is empty or doesn't exist.

Is it possible to do this **just with CSS and without Javascript**?

*edit: changed #column1 width. example had an error, added div ontop.*

Comment: You need to check somewhere whether the second column exists or not. You do so via JS, but could also do so in your template and write an according CSS class (e.g. 'layout-two-col') to the `BODY` tag. Look at the Wordpress default themes, those are build that way.

Comment: On what cases would `column2` be empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually easier if your elements are in the reverse order.

```
<div id='box'>
    <div id='column2'></div>
    <div id='column1'></div>
</div>

#column2 + #column1 { width: 10em }
```

If they must stay in the order you specified, then using the table display properties will do it (without #column1 flowing around #column2 when #column2 is shorter):

```
#box { width: 20em; display: table }
#column1, #column2 { display: table-cell }
#column2 { width: 8em; } /* you'll want to add some margin/padding here */
```

Note that these solutions only cover the case of #column2 not being there.  If you want to see if an element is empty (or not empty), you'll want to use the `:empty` pseudo class chained with `:not`:  `#column2:not(:empty)` (this might not be the exact syntax).

Edit:  other options can include looking to see if #column1 is an only child (`#column1:only-child`) or first/last child when it should be the last/first child (`#column1:first-child`/`#column1:last-child`).

Comment: Why do they have to be in reverse order?

Comment: The `+` selector only works in one direction.  You can select an element that follows a specific element, you can't select an element that precedes a specific element.

Comment: The result I get is the same as setting column1 to auto-width. If column1 has very little content, the div will not expand to all the available space (100% of #box).

Comment: @boadescriptor which solution are you using?

Comment: I can't reproduce:  http://cssdesk.com/AqPNv -- if I remove div#column2, div#column1 takes up the entire width of div#box.

Comment: You're right, my example was incomplete. Edited the question, this is it: http://cssdesk.com/58U4x

Comment: The stray float in there was messing the whole thing up, I've compensated for the extra div as well by setting it to `display: table-row` (`table-caption` would work, too): http://cssdesk.com/phUCV

Answer (score 0):

Div's will allways fall back to 100% width if not defined. So i would set it as follows:

```
#box { width: 20em; }
#column1 {width: auto;}
#column2 {float: left; width: 8em; margin-left: 2em; }
```

You will have to make sure `<div id="column2">..</div>` does not exist though when its not neccesary.

Comment: If #column2 is shorter than #column1, #column1 will flow around #column2.  Most of the time, you don't want this behavior for a 2-column layout.

Comment: If I set the width of #column1 to auto, and the content of column one is one short sentence, then #column1 will only expand to the width of the sentence, not to 100%.

Comment: Try adding min-width: 10em to column1